# Variable changes without the knowledge of after =

Tags: python, arrays, equals

Why do I get an identical array, if I don't change `b`?

```
a=[6,5,4,2,64,23]
b=a;
for k in range(len(a)): a[k]=59-a[k];

print b,a

>>> [53, 54, 55, 57, -5, 36] [53, 54, 55, 57, -5, 36]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have a `reference` to the object  `a`  not a copy, try `b = a[:]`

```
In [1]: a=[6,5,4,2,64,23]

In [2]: b=a;

In [3]: id(a)
Out[3]: 139758187681768

In [4]: id(b)
Out[4]: 139758187681768
In [5]: b is a
Out[5]: True

In [6]: b = a[:]

In [7]: id(a)
Out[7]: 139758187681768

In [8]: id(b)
Out[8]: 139758187615296

In [9]: b is a
Out[9]: False
```

`b = a[:]` creates a new object which is a copy of `a` so any changes in a will **not** affect `b`,

using `b = a` is just a pointer to the same object so changing `a` will change `b` because as we see above `a is b`.

Answer (score 2):

Well thats the concept of a reference.

If you state `b=a`, you **don't** copy the array. Both variables point to the same array. Thus making a modification through one variable (name) is the same as to another one and both variables point to the same array.

One can copy a array in python with `b=a[:]`

Answer (score 2):

`b` references `a`, which means that is is not a copy, but rather something that says: "If you want to know what I am look there" and points to `a`.

If `b` were a copy of a, which is achieved by doing `b=a[:]` then `b` would be a copy of  `a` at that time and not change when `a` changes, as it is not a reference any more as when we did `b=a`.